# Get each numbered data attribute jquery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-data

**HTML**

```
<figure class="video-thumb" 
  data-thumb-0="image2.jpg" 
  data-thumb-1="image3.jpg"
  data-thumb-2="image4.jpg"
  data-thumb-3="image5.jpg"
> 
  <img src="image1.jpg"> 
</figure>
```

I want to get each of these data-thumb-* attributes with jQuery.

I then want to iterate through these using setInterval to swap the src of image1.jpg.

I will end up with the user hovering and seeing the data-thumb-0/1/2/3/4/etc, over the duration of a few seconds.

The reason I have these numbered (data-thumb-0/1/2/3/4/5) is because the CMS pushes these numbers out based on how many thumbs the client has uploaded.

I hope this is enough information, any help seriously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your element in a variable such as `elem`, try this:

```
var thumbs = [], i = 0, attr;
while( attr = elem.getAttribute("data-thumb-"+i)) {
    thumbs[i] = attr;
    i++;
}
```

This will give you an array of thumbnails.

Comment: Did not want to use javascript as am not as comfortable. Adjusted slightly to work - http://jsfiddle.net/tomsansome/hGxse/. Thanks very much Niet.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with basic JavaScript, you should not be using jQuery...

Comment: You are getting good advice here, I would take it if I were you.  You REALLY shouldn't be using jquery if you don't even understand the basics of javascript.  Going your intended route will only result in headaches later.  I myself went down the same path once, and it was indeed a mistake.  Jquery is a tool to utilize once you have a proper grasp of the concepts.

Comment: maybe I should have written **Did not want to use _pure_ javascript as am not as comfortable**...

Comment: Again, you really should be using pure javascript.  Once you have a good understanding, then maybe pickup a tool like jquery.